# Redux - state does not update correctly after typing something in a TextInput component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, state

I did all the instructions for a redux tutorial correctly.  But after running the program, when I try to enter a value in the email or password `TextInput`, the value is not placed in it and the email input is emptied immediately.  I do not know where I did the wrong thing.  But I think the action is not working properly.  I hope you will guide me.

---

In Action directory > index.js

```
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASS_CHANGED, USER_LOGIN_ATEMT, USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, USER_LOGIN_FAILED } from "./types";
export const emailChanged = (text) => {
   return {
      type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
      payload: text
   }
}
export const passChanged = (text) => {
   return {
      type: PASS_CHANGED,
      payload: text
   }
}
export const loginUser = ({ email, pass }) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_ATEMT });
      fetch('', {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: pass
         })
      }).then((response) => response.json()).
         then((responseJson) => {
            if (responseJson === 'Data Matched') {
               loginUserSuccess(dispatch);
            } else {
               loginUserFailed(dispatch);
            }
         }).catch((error) => { alert(error) });
   }
}
const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS });
}

const loginUserFailed = (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_FAILED });
}
```

---

In Action directory > types.js

```
export const EMAIL_CHANGED = 'EMAIL_CHANGED';
export const PASS_CHANGED = 'PASS_CHANGED';
export const USER_LOGIN_ATEMT = 'USER_LOGIN_ATEMT';
export const USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS';
export const USER_LOGIN_FAILED = 'USER_LOGIN_FAILED';
```

---

In components directory > LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { emailChanged, passChanged, loginUser } from '../actions/index';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  onEmailChange(text) {
    this.props.emailChanged(text)
  }
  onPassChange(text) {
    this.props.passChanged(text)
  }
  onLoginUser() {
    const { email, pass } = this.props;
    this.loginUser({ email, pass });
  }
  renderButton() {
    if (this.props.loading) {
      return (<ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />);
    } else {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onLoginUser.bind(this)} >
          <Text>Continue...</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          onChangeText={() => this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
          value={this.props.email}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Pass"
          onChangeText={() => this.onPassChange.bind(this)}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          value={this.props.pass}
        />
        <Text>{this.props.error}</Text>
        {this.renderButton()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    email: state.auth.email,
    pass: state.auth.pass,
    loading: state.auth.loading,
    error: state.auth.error
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { emailChanged, passChanged, loginUser })(LoginForm);
```

---

In reducers directory > AuthReducer.js

```
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASS_CHANGED, USER_LOGIN_ATEMT, USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, USER_LOGIN_FAILED } from '../actions/types';
const initialState = {
   email: '',
   pass: '',
   loading: false,
   error: ''
}
const AuthReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   console.log(action);
   switch (action.type) {
      case EMAIL_CHANGED:
         return { ...state, 
            email: state.email.concat({
               key: Math.random(),
               value: action.payload
            })
          }
      case PASS_CHANGED:
         return { ...state, pass: action.payload }
      case USER_LOGIN_ATEMT:
         return { ...state, loading: true }
      case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
         return { ...state, ...initialState }
      case USER_LOGIN_FAILED:
         return { ...state, loading: false, pass: '', error: 'اشتباه وارد شده است' }
      default:
         return state;
   }
}
export default AuthReducer;
```

---

In reducers directory > index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from '../reducers/AuthReducer';
const reducers = combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer
});
export default reducers;
```

---

In App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text, FlatList, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))}>
        <LoginForm />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

---

In index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

---

My package.json

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-redux": "^7.2.2",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`email` is initially an empty string, when you dispatch `EMAIL_CHANGED` you attempt to concatenate an object with keys `key` and `value` to it. Your component is accessing only `state.auth.email`. I'm absolutely sure there *should* be an error being thrown somewhere. The `onChangeText`  value from the text input is *the entire* value, not the delta, so you shouldn't concatenate or append anything, just fully replace the existing email state (*You got this part right for the password, actually*).

There is also an issue with how you are attaching your handler.

```
onChangeText={() => this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
```

This drops the `onChangeText` value and passes undefined to your handler.

## Solution

Update the reducer case to correctly update the `email` value.

```
case EMAIL_CHANGED:
  return {
    ...state, 
    email: action.payload,
  }
```

Update the handler to consume the changed value.

```
onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
```

Hint: to save the binding of this you can either do that in a `constructor` or use an arrow function.

```
onEmailChange = (text) => {
  this.props.emailChanged(text)
}

...

onChangeText={this.onEmailChange}
```

Second hint: You can directly attach the passed handler to the input and save a function declaration and `this` binding.

```
onChangeText={this.props.onEmailChange}
```

If for some reason you need the random key value (random values are poor keys/ids as they aren't guaranteed to be unique) then update as follows:

Provide valid initial state

```
const initialState = {
  email: {}, // <-- empty object, provides object to destructure from in UI
  ...
}
```

Fully replace the `email` object

```
case EMAIL_CHANGED:
  return { ...state, 
    email: {
      key: Math.random(),
      value: action.payload
    }
  }
```

Access the email value correctly in the component

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    email: state.auth.email.value, // <-- get the email value
    ...
  }
}
```